# facebook messenger 404 file not found

Tags: node.js, facebook-messenger

I am trying to follow the example outlined here of creating a simple echo bot for Facebook Messenger https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/quickstart

I got most of it working, except for the sending message response part. I keep getting this error

```
Error sending message:  { [Error: Not Found]
...
  error: 
   { [Error: cannot POST /v2.6/me/messages?access_token=<PAGE_TOKEN> (404)]
      status: 404,
      text: '404 File Not Found',
      method: 'POST'
```

I am not sure why I would get a "404 File Not Found" error, and don't know what to do to fix it. Any advice or suggestion would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what the issue was, but I was able to upload a message try using [request](https://npmjs.com/package/request) instead of [superagent](https://npmjs.com/package/superagent).